# MSEdge Driver not launching Brwoser using selenium

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge

I am using selenium to automate MS Edge (chromium) browser. I have downloaded correct driver i.e v79.0.309.43 which is same for driver and browser.

but when I run code , it simply shows message that it is launching on multiple ports .See Screenshot below=

[image]

Can someone point out what is issue here?

Thanks,
Nilesh

Answer (score 0):

I test with **Microsoft Edge(Chromium) Beta** version 79.0.309.43 and the same version of Microsoft Edge(Chromium) WebDriver and it works. You could refer to the code below and change the path to your owns:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions; 
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeOptions;


public class Edgeauto {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "your\\path\\to\\edge\\webdriver\\msedgedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge Beta\\Application\\msedge.exe");
        EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions().merge(chromeOptions);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(edgeOptions);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    }
}
```

Also please remember to have the location of Edge Beta and msedgedriver.exe on your **PATH**.